# tables created via JDBC in Athena not appearing in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

When i create a table using  JDBC driver with Amazon Athena its not showing up in the Athena Console but does appear when execute a `show tables in mydatabase` command via jdbc (and vice versa).  Any ideas why I this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

my jdbc calls and console were in different regions! doh!